# XML puro em PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-service

Estou fazendo uma requisição a um web service (feito em delphi), pelo PHP enviando um XML e recebendo uma resposta.

O que quero é poder mostrar o XML exatamente como ele é.

Código que uso:
`$getData` é o XML de requisição

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://192.168.1.164:8080/wsdl/IComanda");
$obj = $client->Requisicao($gtData);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($obj);
print_r ($xml);
```

Só que o que recebo é parecido com isso (exemplo tirado do PHP):

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [title] => Forty What?
  [from] => Joe
  [to] => Jane
  [body] =>
)
```

Como faço para exibir o XML puro recebido do web service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repare que ao usar [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-string.php) você está interpretando o XML de resposta.

Se quiser o XML puro basta usar a variável anterior:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://192.168.1.164:8080/wsdl/IComanda");
$obj = $client->Requisicao($gtData);

// Só para garantir que o código XML será exibido no navegador
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');

echo $obj;
```

Comment: Alysson, acho que o navegador que está omitindo as tags. Veja como fica o retorno com o `header()`.

Comment: O erro que aparece nesse teu código é esse: error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name

Comment: Poderia testar o seguinte: `var_dump($obj);` ?

Comment: Tirei header() e o echo e fiz isso que você disse.
Perfeito. É isso mesmo, obrigado cara.